# How do you get value?

Tags: javascript

I wanna get a value in object.

```js
const object = {
      foo: {
        hoge: []
      }
    }
    
console.log(object["foo"]); //-> {hoge:[]}
console.log(object["foo"]["hoge"]); //-> []
```

? is String.

Is there a person who can solve it?

I have a answer. Using `eval`

```js
console.log(eval("object.foo.hoge]")); //-> []
```

but, I do not want to use `eval`

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for?

Comment: I want to get a value in the form `obj[?]` Without eval.

Answer (score 0):

`object["foo"]["hoge"]` will do what you want.  Note that because the keys are valid identifiers, you can use the shorthand attribute access syntax: `object.foo.hoge`.

Comment: I would like to conclude in []. Therefore, you can not write like `[foo] [hoge]` or `foo.hoge` .

Comment: @JunyaKono That's not possible. (Not without changing `object`, anyway.)

Comment: @JunyaKono You might be interested in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/), which has a helper for this: `_.get(object, 'foo.hoge')`.

Comment: that's cool! Thanks!